# get the content type of an email attachment in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to get the content type of an attachment which is sent to email...I am attaching it from my local drive.. How do I get the content type of that to save it in the db... In the mailer file, I tried like the below. But it didn't work. Please help.

```
files.each do |file|
      attachment "application/octet-stream" do |a|
      a.body = file.read
      a.filename = file.original_filename
      a.content_type = `file --raw --brief "#{file}"`.chomp
      puts "The content type of the file is...",a.content_type
    end
```

THe above shows error as "sub type missing: "ERROR: cannot open `56.png' (No such file or directory)""

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
a.content_type = `file --raw --brief "#{file}"`.chomp
```

To

```
a.content_type = `file --raw --brief "#{file.original_filename}"`.chomp
```

Comment: The above didnt work.. I tried to using mime-types gem also...And implemented like below...                               a.content_type = MIME::Types.type_for(file).first.content_type... It didnt work... Please help